# Which of the following is LC lossless function?

Tags: filter, passive-networks

Which of the following is LC lossless function and why? Pick one of the valid LC lossless functions and realize it using Foster-I and Cauer-I form.

[image: Lossless function]

I have been trying to solve this question for sometime now and still am not able to. I posted a similar one as well but did not get any response. Link below:
[Confusion with determining lossless function](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/616586/confusion-with-determining-lossless-function)

I only want to know which is the valid LC lossless function and why? Also why the others are not? I am only been able to find out the option iv is not a LC lossless function.
Can someone please guide me? I have exam coming soon.

**Reminder: I only want to know which is valid LC lossless function and why, and why others are not valid. What condition did not they satisfy. The conditions for determining lossless is provided on the link given above, that confusion with determining lossless function one**

Comment: 1 and 3 don't have alternating roots, and also have RHP zeroes for P(s)+Q(s). The latter is true for the transfer function in the other question, too. 4 has same degrees for numerator and denominator. Only 2 looks lossless.

Comment: In 1 and 3, is not sqrt(-3) alternating, it gives root(3)i and -root(3)i for (s^2 + 3)?

Comment: That's just the nature of the complex root: it comes as a complex conjugate pair: \$s=a\pm jb\$. But if you look at all the roots in II (for example), both poles and zeroes alternate (considering only the number, for clarity): z=3, p=4, z=6, p=9. That's z,p,z,p -- alternating.

Comment: oh ok. i thought you meant something else. Thank you for the help.